# App header not explicitly defined but present

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The app I'm working on has a predefined header that is not present in the layout.

**layout/activity_wallpaper.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@id/screen_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/loading_indicator"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

which renders as:

[image]

"App title" is present in:

**xml/wallpaper.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wallpaper
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:settingsActivity="com.dayafternight.wallpaper.SettingsActivity"
    android:thumbnail="@drawable/app_icon">
</wallpaper>
```

The layout is loaded in an activity:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpaper);
```

but it doesn't explicitly refer the title. Where is the title inserted in the layout?

Grepping for the title gives an entry in strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_name">App title</string>
```

and AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:isGame="false" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
```

How can I discard the application name as part of my activity's layout?

Answer (score 0):

We could do it in couple ways:

1. By setting ActionBar not to show title.

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   ```

After `setContentView(..);` call.

2. By theme.

   ```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoTitleActionBar">
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
   ```

And apply this theme to the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleActionBar">
```

3. By setting empty title to the toolbar if we are using one.

   ```
   <ToolBar
     ...
     app:title=""
   ../>
   ```